# How to extract date time from dtype('<M8[ns]') in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

my ots column has : `2021-04-03 14:01:22.791856`
its dtype is `dtype('<M8[ns]')`
how do I get only `2021-04-03 14:01:22` ?

Comment: Could you please clarify; the data type of your output should be string? pandas datetime?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use this:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html

considering that is your time column in the pandas dataframe:

```
df['time'] = df['time'].dt.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
```

Comment: AttributeError: 'Series' object has no attribute 'strftime'

Comment: forget to put dt there, please check the update answer